# Creating Dynamic ng-model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, loops, angularjs-scope

Following is the working code - http://plnkr.co/edit/6lRhiTd1BrKRdThY0WNB?p=preview

In this if you select the number from drop down and fill data then click and check console you will see the result like -

```
[
    Object { start_time="12Start", end_time="12END"},
    Object { start_time="34start", end_time="786"},
    Object { start_time="123", end_time="5656"},
    Object { start_time="098", end_time="77"},
    Object { start_time="75757", end_time="57567"}
]
```

Now If you check, there are two arrays - `$scope.shiftstart` | `$scope.shiftend`

I am looping through these but one problem with this approach is that-

1) It needs to be dependent on the equal length of arrays.

2) If some one leaves the first end time input field then it comes as *undefined* in the console.

What I am thinking is to not to use - separate `ng-model="shiftstart[shiftnumber]"` & `ng-model="shiftend[shiftnumber]"` instead I could use ONE single array containing multiple objects but I am unable to integrate the solution, let me know what I can amend in my code to make that happen.

Comment: I have no glue what it is that you're actually trying to do...

Comment: @Yoshi I want `ng-model="shiftstart[shiftnumber]"` & `ng-model="shiftend[shiftnumber]"` to be used as a single entity like `ng-model="shift.start_time[shiftnumber]"` & `ng-model="shift.end_time[shiftnumber]"` so that it will produce the same array of object result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I do understand your question correctly, I think you're way overcomplicating stuff. If you simple want to:

- a) have a list of shifts, from which one can be selected, and
- b) be able to edit that selected shift

then the following is all you need:

**ctrl**:

```
$scope.shifts = [
  { nr: 1, start_time: "12Start", end_time: "12END" },
  { nr: 2, start_time: "34start", end_time: "786"   },
  { nr: 3, start_time: "123",     end_time: "5656"  },
  { nr: 4, start_time: "098",     end_time: "77"    },
  { nr: 5, start_time: "75757",   end_time: "57567" }
];

$scope.active = null;
```

**view-demo**:

```
<h3>Select a shift</h3>
<select
  data-ng-model="active"
  data-ng-options="shift as shift.nr for shift in shifts"
></select>

<div data-ng-show="active">
  <h3>Edit start/end</h3>
  start time <input data-ng-model="active.start_time"><br>
  snd time <input data-ng-model="active.end_time">
</div>
```

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/fibilalaciha/1/

Comment: Yeah I think its better if i provide pre filled data